# How to find list definition data in SQL

Tags: sql, sharepoint

We're running SharePoint 2007 on a small farm. One department in our company has a site with a customized Tasks list. This list has 3 content types which successively inherit from Task.

Task : Purchase : Renewable Purchase : Contract

We just used the out-of-the-box tools and interface to construct this list and it's content types and site columns. We did **not** modify the core Task content type.

The customer had me go in and alter the names of some columns, and create a few new ones. I also did this with the normal List Settings interface.

Now when they attempt to edit certain items the get the following error:

"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14"

I looked up the error and found that it indicates that the SQL transaction log for that content database is full. This is not the case. Further research turned up people saying that they also got the same error after similar modifications to their lists. It appears that this error is being thrown incorrectly.

My feeling based on these similar reports is that SharePoint got confused and assigned duplicate values for the *colName* property of one or more fields in the list definition data. For nearly every report I'm reading, however, they're using hand-crafted content types which they manually added as features - this gives them a Schema.xml file to edit, which I don't seem to have. No one seems to be having this problem using only the normal interface.

So I'd like to check for duplicate values in the list definition data but I don't know how to query it. Where does this data live in the content db? If I were to find it, would it be acceptable to modify it?

## Errors

After obtaining ULSViewer I did an edit operation on a test item in the list. One error that popped up was:

Unexpected query execution failure, error code 137. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. "Must declare the scalar variable "@@LevelSELECT"." Query text (if available): "BEGIN TRAN;DECLARE @@iRet INT,@DN nvarchar(256),@LN nvarchar(128),@@S uniqueidentifier,@@Level tinyint,@@DocUIVersion int,@ExtraItemSize bigint;SET @@iRet = 0;SET @@S='5E0E6D27-0D10-428F-B6E4-5CC7F2921369';SET @@Level=1;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512;SELECT @ExtraItemSize = 0  EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateListItem @SiteId='5E0E6D27-0D10-428F-B6E4-5CC7F2921369',@WebId='AAE6409B-325A-48D2-8C92-FA73858AA20B', @ListID = '38EC3BA0-F83B-4A5E-A654-AC541D2F9769', @ItemID=1310, @RowOrdinal = 0,@ReturnRowset = 1,@ItemDirName=@DN OUTPUT,@ItemLeafName=@LN OUTPUT,@UserId=3,@TimeNow = '20110215 15:39:04',@MajorVersionsLimit=0,@MajorMinorVersionsLimit=0, @NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion OUTPUT,@Level=@@Level OUTPUT,@IsDocLib=0, @tp_Version = 1, @tp_ContentTypeId = ?, @nvarchar1 = ?, @nvarchar3 = ?, @nvarchar4 = ?, @int1 = ?, @ntext2 = ?, @datetime1 = ?, @datetime2 = ?, @int3 = ?, @nvarchar5 = ?, @ntext9 = ?, @ntext3 = ?, @ntext4 = ?, @tp_ContentType = ?, @datetime3 = ?, @int5 = ?, @float3 = ?, @ntext10 = ?, @ntext5 = ?, @nvarchar21 = ?, @datetime4 = ?, @nvarchar10 = ?, @nvarchar20 = ?, @nvarchar22 = ?, @nvarchar23 = ?, @nvarchar19 = ?, @nvarchar24 = ?, @tp_Modified = ?, @tp_ModerationStatus = ?, @tp_ItemOrder = 131000.000000000, @Size = 182, @ExtraItemSize = @ExtraItemSize ,@CreateItemVersion=1,@ItemName=N'TEST001',@eventData=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,@acl=0xF3FE0000010000000000000006000000050000006110030CB000000030000000EF12433CB001000033000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F8A0000006110030CB0000000960000000010010830000000FFFFFF3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END   EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateItemJunctionsCurrentVersion @SiteId = '5E0E6D27-0D10-428F-B6E4-5CC7F2921369', @DirName = @DN, @LeafName = @LN, @NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion, @Level = @@LevelSELECT @ExtraItemSize = 0  EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateListItem @SiteId='5E0E6D27-0D10-428F-B6E4-5CC7F2921369',@WebId='AAE6409B-325A-48D2-8C92-FA73858AA20B', @ListID = '38EC3BA0-F83B-4A5E-A654-AC541D2F9769', @ItemID=1310, @RowOrdinal = 1,@ReturnRowset = 1,@UserId=3,@TimeNow = '20110215 15:39:04',@MajorVersionsLimit=0,@MajorMinorVersionsLimit=0, @NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion OUTPUT,@Level=@@Level OUTPUT,@IsDocLib=0, @tp_Version = 1, @Size = 0, @ExtraItemSize = @ExtraItemSize ,@ItemName=N'TEST001',@eventData=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,@acl=0xF3FE0000010000000000000006000000050000006110030CB000000030000000EF12433CB001000033000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F8A0000006110030CB0000000960000000010010830000000FFFFFF3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END  EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,'18E5EBF4-97FA-4B92-AA3E-37CC601A4DBB'; EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,'8B12A69E-C342-473B-89F7-A39913F5382F'; EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,'6F7FF8F6-AC72-493B-AF89-CBE031816F97'; EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,'45AFEE8A-879E-4DAA-BC9F-FFA192A348B0'; EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,'D399FC56-0966-40B5-BDF9-6B7D47E3391D'; COMMIT TRAN; DONE: RETURN;"

The error just before that is: "Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80040e14"

## Resolution

This turned out not to be a naming collision, but an issue with version control enabled on large lists. My alterations to the list apparently just catalyzed it. There's a hotfix for this (support.microsoft.com/kb/948945) which we applied last night. Everything seems to be in order now. Thanks everyone for the insight.

Comment: which Sharepoint version? 2007? Regarding your last sentence: acceptable to modify it: **no!** - for any version. One more thing "Now when they attempt to edit certain items" - when exactly does the error occur? When you edit existing list items?

Comment: As mentioned in the first line, this is 2007. The error is thrown when you enter edit mode and try to save. It's not clear why some items are throwing the error and others are not. (Nothing obvious like 'anything created before the changes is fine' or whatever.) *Most* items throw the error.

Comment: You sure did point out the version... ;-) Saying that this is "random" as in some items throw the error some don't as well as you having created everything via the UI points at a DB problem/service pack, not at a duplicate name problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions from duplicate fields look differently than the `HRESULT` error you're getting.

Are you sure that the transaction logs are not full? Did you truncate the log files of the content database? Did you check the disk size of the hard disk your content db's is residing on? Are all the other databases ok? Most sources I have looked at suggest exactly that: full disks.

Additionally Microsoft says that a wrong service pack / update might be the culprit - did you happen to install a SP or hotfix lately? ["0x80040E14" or "HTTP 500" error message when you connect to your Windows SharePoint Services Web site after you install a Windows SharePoint Services service pack or a security update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841216)

For further investigation: Did you check the ULS logs (use the [ULS Viewer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) for that)? Usually there is a lot of useful information in there you don't see via the user interface.

Do not try to modify anything in the content database - this is a big no-no in the Sharepoint world.

Comment: I've had our DB Guy look into the SQL space issue - he's adamant that this is not the problem (transaction log not full, disk space ok, db set to autogrow, etc.).

We have not performed any updates on this installation in quite some time. The problem *only* occurred *immediately* after making the changes to the columns, so I'm considering that my first line of attack. Finally - we have logging turned off apparently; the last entry in the log in the 12 hive was months ago. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I'll also mention that no other sites or lists on the portal are having this issue - it's only this one list that I altered columns on. We have many other sites and many lists in each; all others are fine.

Comment: Good information you provide there, that it only happens in that one list! Yes, I'm talking about the log in the 12 hive (use the ULS Viewer from Microsoft to have a live-view for when the error occurs). The list definitions you can easily check out via the Sharepoint Manager - but that's tedious work. You say it's only one list - any harm re-creating this list (create temp list, copy items there, delete list, create list anew)?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of long-running workflow instances associated with that list (reminders sent when a contract needs renewal, for instance). I don't know exactly how I'd do that other than with the Export to Spreadsheet option, and that seems a little sketchy to me. I'm currently trying to get information from ULSViewer in order to test my hypothesis about the colName values. SPManager seems like a decent tool but I can see now what you meant about the tedium.

Comment: This turned out not to be a naming collision, but an issue with version control enabled on large lists. My alterations to the list apparently just catalyzed it. There's a hotfix for this (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948945) which we applied last night. Everything seems to be in order now. Thanks for the pointers and perspective.

Answer (score 1):

[SharePoint manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) allows you to get a schema xml for each columns, content types and lists. 
You can also get the [spField.SchemaXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.schemaxml.aspx) property if you are running code on the object model.

Thanks for adding the error. That seems to be the same error I experienced a few years back with manually editing and or restoring a database backup. Unfortunately it is so many years ago I cannot remember the details.

However I think you should continue checking the database column names for the key fields.

From what I can remember, there appeared to be two different pieces of code SharePoint uses to generate some of the on the fly SQL statements and when our manually edited fields managed to get tangled, the sql code to generate the first part of the query no longer matched the second part. I pulled out the query and tried to run it, but I am pretty sure this did not give out any useful details.

Unfortunately I am pretty sure we were still in dev when this error occurred and chose to rebuild rather than iron out the issue.

Sorry I cannot add anything more useful.